# Material sidebar icon animation (e.g. Gmail)

Tags: android, android-animation, material-design

I am investigating if there is a 15+ API to implement sidebar icon transitions as displayed on the video by google:

http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/v_2/material_ext_publish/0B0NGgBg38lWWRm5QODB0bk95SUE/patterns-loadingimages-loading-070901_Load_Add_Animation_xhdpi_002.mp4

If I use the classic ObjectAnimator.fromFloat() the code will be huge and cumbersome.

Is there a way to reposition the items with a reasonable length of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following library with sample.

https://github.com/neokree/MaterialNavigationDrawer

You will get the perfect result as you want